# awk command for searching multiple patterns

Tags: shell, awk

I have a log file which keeps on updating.
there is a function for updating the file.
Upon successful operation function inserts "status 0" in log file else status 1.
What i am looking for is -
I want to write a monitoring script which will open this log file and will search for today's date AND status code.

Please note -
there is no such date wise separation. Logs of yesterday and today's are stored in same file.

below is a sample code i tried but i want to search for today's date as well-

```
current_date=`date +%d-%b-%y`
echo $current_date
cd /complete/application/logs

status=`tail -10 agent.log | awk '/"$current_date"/&&/Agent Exited/ {print $0}'`
echo $status
if [ "$status" == "<0>" ]
then
echo "Log Agent Status on `hostname` is running fine."
else
echo "Log Agent status on `hostname` is not running ."
fi
```

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  In a question like this, it would be helpful to show a few lines from the log file, or truncated versions of the lines if the lines are really long.  You should also show the expected output from the data you show.  Without that, we're working blind and can't reliably help you.  How many such lines are there in the log file?  How many lines per day in total, and how many that report on the exit status?  Why 10 lines instead of 100, or 1?

Comment: how is status ever going to equal `"<0>"` when you set it in the command above. It will either be empty or every line that matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk "/$current_date/ && /Agent Exited/"
```

If you can't see any output immediately, this can happen because the stdout of `tail -f` get's buffered when going to a pipe. (This is done by the libc).

On Linux, you can adjust or disable this buffering using the `stdbuf` command:

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -f logfile | awk "/$current_date/ && /Agent Exited/"
```

The above command executes the `tail -f` with an output buffer of zero size making the output appear immediately on screen. There is a comparable command for MacOS and BSD.

**Update**

Oh, I missed that you are using `tail -10` instead of `tail -f`. The buffering problem should not be a problem then, however I'll keep the above text for your information.

Comment: thanks for your response.
but its not returning anything :(

Comment: Does @klashxx answer work? It should do the same. If not, please publish  the line from log that should me matched.

Comment: actually, you cannot tell what line would be the last line in the log file. log file keeps updating. need to check for today's status whether it is o or 1

Comment: @Shyam This command is doing what you want. If it does not work for you, then you missed to describe your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the quoting mechanism:

```
status=`tail -10 agent.log | awk '/'"${current_date}"'/&&/Agent Exited/ {print $0}'`
```

To avoid code injection will be definitely better:

```
awk -v cd="${current_date}" 'match($0,cd) && /Agent Exited/'
```

So your code will look like:

```
status=`tail -10 agent.log | awk -v cd="${current_date}" 'match($0,cd) && /Agent Exited/'`
```

Note that you omit `print $0` as it's the defalut action for `awk` when an expression is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Why on earth are you using match for this ? `$0~cd` would be sufficient,

Comment: just more readable @JID

Comment: Not sure i agree but each to their own :)